# Non-initialized vs null values of reference types

Tags: c#, reference, null

Is there a difference between reference type variable being non initialized or having null value?
I read somewhere that non-init means null but on other place I read something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that *fields* are implicitly initialized to `null`, so this only affects variables. In pure c# you **can't query** the value of an uninitialized field (you need "definite assignment"), so it is a non-question.

You **can** do this by abusing IL though - by declaring an `out` parameter, and using `DynamicMethod` to write a method that doesn't assign it (valid in IL, but not in C#). And then you find that you will see `null`s.

This in turn is due to an IL flag (`.locals init`) that says "clear the stack for me before entering this method" on the **calling** (C#) code. The C# compiler always sets this flag. If you again abuse IL to write a method that doesn't set this flag, you can probably see garbage. It could be **anything**. But by this point, you deserve the exceptions you get :)

Here's an example of the first (not the second, which is more complex):

```
delegate void AbuseMe(out object foo);
static void Main() {
    DynamicMethod dyn = new DynamicMethod("Foo",
        typeof(void), new[] { typeof(object).MakeByRefType() });
    dyn.GetILGenerator().Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    AbuseMe method = (AbuseMe) dyn.CreateDelegate(typeof(AbuseMe));
    object obj; // this **never** gets assigned, by **any** code
    method(out obj);
    Console.WriteLine(obj == null);
}
```

For clarification, the `DynamicMethod` code is simply writing the equivalent of this code, not legal in C#:

```
static void Foo(out object whatever) { } // note, whatever is not assigned
```

This works because *as far as the CLR is concerned* `out` doesn't exist - there is only `ref`. So this isn't invalid IL - it is only the language (C#) that puts meaning to `out` and demands that it be assigned a value.

The problem is that `Main()` still has the `.locals init` flag; so behind the scenes `obj` **is** cleared to `null` (well, the entire stack space is simply wiped). If I compiled from IL without that flag (and had some other code in place to make the stack space dirty) I could see garbage. You can see more about `.locals init` on [Liran Chen's](http://blog.liranchen.com/2010/07/behind-locals-init-flag.html) blog.

But to answer the question:

- for fields: uninitialized reference-type fields are `null` - guaranteed by the spec
- for variables: **you can't ask**, but *as an implementation detail* (that should not be depended on): yes, it will be `null` *even though* you can't ask ;p

Comment: Ok, that is pretty freaky sh!t!  :)

Comment: Jeffrey Richter in his book "CLR Via C#, 3rd edition" mentions that variables are always initialized by CLR to `null`. He also says that actually it's not necessary for C# compiler to forbid using non-initialized variables, but the compiler still has this restriction.

Comment: @Dmitry exactly, which is why I stressed "should not be depended on". This behaviour is not defined by the C# spec (it doesn't need to be : the entire scenario is already precluded), so any implementation is valid. "Set the locals to monotonically increasing bytes" would be a perfectly legal implementation ;p

Comment: @Dmitry and that CLR "rule" is, unless I am mistaken, driven by the `.locals init` flag. IIRC you can omit this, and let the chaos commence.

Answer (score 4):

"It depends"

For normal *member variables* when a value is not specified in the declaration then the variable assume the appropriate default value (`null` for reference types). That is, `class A { string X; }` is the same as `class A { string X = null; }`.

For *local variables* it is an error to access them before a value can be proven to have been assigned. Even though their type "defaults" to null (for reference types), they are not default implicitly assigned! That is, `string F () { string x; return x; }` is a compile-time error.

Remember: `null` is `null` :-)