# Fixing the 'Use of unassigned local variable' with a null assignment. Why?

Tags: c#, exception, variable-assignment

With a piece of code like this, the compiler complains on `c.MyProperty`:

```
MyClass c;

try { throw new Exception(); }
catch (Exception) { }

c.MyProperty = 2; // "Use of unassigned local variable 'c'".
```

Yet it doesn't complain if you assign a `null` to `c` in initialization:

```
MyClass c = null;

try { throw new Exception(); }
catch (Exception) { }

c.MyProperty = 2; // no complains this time.
```

So, why does this work?  If `c` wasn't assigned a `null` and the compiler hypothetically allowed it, wouldn't the same exception be thrown at `c.MyProperty`, **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**?

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting, my guess would be though that this code (second version) would still throw an exception at Runtime.. it's likely just a visual studio issue that is not picking up the null assignment - Just a guess ?

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770426/non-initialized-vs-null-values-of-reference-types

Answer (score 86, accepted):

When you assign `null` to the variable you're telling the compiler to back off because you know better than him so he should not complain about this.

This is probably due to the fact that assigning `null` is considered to imply an explicit action by the developer.

Comment: Although that made me laugh, I'm still not closer to an answer.

Comment: @Andreas: This is the actual answer, this is why it is allowed. C# will let you **intentionally** shoot your self in the foot. It just won't let you do it _unintentionally_.

Comment: Although the way I answered was meant to add some humor to my opinion, I genuinely think that this can be why the compiler stops complaining so it's a valid answer even if it at the days end is not the correct one.

Comment: I always thought compilers were she's.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the C# Language specification v. 4.0 section 1.6.6.2 "Method body and local variables" states the following:

> A method body can declare variables that are specific to the invocation of the method. Such variables are called local variables.
>
> [skipped]
>
> C# requires a local variable to be **definitely assigned** before its value can be obtained.

This is to avoid letting you to shoot yourself in the foot, as Binary Worrier neatly pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way, the compiler is not telling you that it is going to throw a null reference and therefore it can't compile, but rather that one of the conditions aren't met that are required to compile, i.e. that it has to be definitely assigned.

According to the spec null is a c# literal: "The  null-literal can be implicitly converted to a reference type or nullable type"

As well as in terms of assignments: (taken from the spec)

**Start of quote taken from the spec**

**5.3.3** Precise rules for determining definite assignment
In order to determine that each used variable is definitely assigned, the compiler must use a process that is equivalent to the one described in this section.

The compiler processes the body of each function member that has one or more initially unassigned variables. For each initially unassigned variable v, the compiler determines a definite assignment state for v at each of the following points in the function member:

·         At the beginning of each statement

·         At the end point (§8.1) of each statement

·         On each arc which transfers control to another statement or to the end point of a statement

·         At the beginning of each expression

·         At the end of each expression

**End of quote**

So even though null is not actually pointing to an object in memory, it does fulfill the requirements of being definitely assigned and that is why the compiler allows it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this exception is that you've not assigned a default value for the variable e.g

```
if (Request.Files != null  && Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                 Image = Request.Files.AllKeys[0];
            }
var stream  = new FileStream(Image,FileMode.Open);
```

now the Image variable will give compiler error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'Image'

That is due to the reason that there is possibility that condition becomes true and control will never get to know what the Image variable is . so either place an else block or assign a default value as below.

```
string Image = "";
if (Request.Files != null  && Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                 Image = Request.Files.AllKeys[0];
            }
var stream  = new FileStream(Image,FileMode.Open);
```